# In java, how would I make a calculation where the greatest number is subtracted by the smaller number?

Tags: java

If I get two totals as an input, where the first and second number may vary in which is larger, how would I set the calculation to always be the greater number subtracted by the smaller one?

Comment: What have you tried? People are much more likely to help you if you can demonstrate that you have attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: why have you not accepted any answers for the questions you have asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
Math.abs(a - b)
```

Answer (score 9):

I would use something like that:

```
public int sub(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    return Math.max(firstNumber, secondNumber) - Math.min(firstNumber, secondNumber);
}
```

or:

```
public int sub(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    return Math.abs(firstNumber - secondNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

substract both and return the absolute value

Answer (score 1):

The `Math` class provides a few methods that can do that for you, or you can just do a simple swap of values like that:

```
public int sub(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {

    if( firstNumber < secondNumber ) {
        int temp = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = firstNumber;
        firstNumber = temp;
    }
    return firstNumber - secondNumber;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just return `secondNumber - firstNumber` if the if condition is `true`? Why swap out with `temp`?

Comment: @CrackerJack9 There are a lot of ways to accomplish that, I'm just giving one possibility. Instead of two `if` I'm just creating a new variable, at that point I guess it's just a matter of choice.

Comment: @tolnicolas you still wouldn't need two `if`s, just subtract different directions in each. If they're equal, it won't matter which way they go, so far less efficient to create a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
       public int sub(int a, int b) {
          if(a > b){
            return a - b;
          }
          else if (b > a) {
            return b - a;
          }
          else return 0;
       }
```